# Calculating gradient from finite difference results

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

I am solving the steady-state heat equation in two dimensions:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(k\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\right) + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(k\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}\right) = 0$$

I have verified my code against analytical solutions. The temperature field solves without a problem, but when I use the temperatures to calculate the magnitude of the gradient I get results that don't make sense (at least not to me).

Here is the temperature field result (which appears normal to me):

[image]

Basically, there is a high temperature boundary condition on the top of the right-hand side, and low temperature boundary condition on the left-hand side separated by a low conductivity barrier with a zero-flux boundary above it. But when I try to plot the calculated magnitude of the heat flux gradient, I get this:

[image]

My understanding is that the heat flux contours should be perpendicular to the temperature contours in the first plot. Instead, I'm seeing these localized hot-spots in areas where the heat flux is changing directions.

I have tried finer meshes and uniform meshes, they all show the same oddity. This is how I am calculating the magnitude of the heat flux:

$$|q| = \sqrt{q_x^2 + q_y^2}$$

where

$$q_x = -k\frac{dT}{dx}=-k\frac{T_{i+1,j}-T_{i-1,j}}{2\Delta x}$$

and

$$q_y = -k\frac{dT}{dy}=-k\frac{T_{i,j+1}-T_{i,j-1}}{2\Delta y}$$

Am I missing something here? I've spent days pouring over my code and making sure my T's are crossed and my I's are dotted. So I'm reaching out to the mathematics community in hopes that you all can identify something that I missed.

Comment: Well, could you include the reasoning why magnitude of heat flux contours should be orthogonal to temperature contours? Because if my calculations are right, then they won't be necessarily orthogonal.

Comment: Like Evgeny said, the fact that the gradient field (flux) itself is perpendicular to the heat contours (the level sets of the temperature), does not mean that its magnitude's contour should be perpendicular to that.

Comment: @Evgeny, I suppose you are implying that it is possible that nothing is wrong with the second plot? That'd be good news to me!

Comment: Taking into account that flux magnitude contour lines don't need to be orthogonal to heat contours, I think that your second plot is OK. Maybe it lacks some more resolution for grid at low conductivity barrier but I think it's still OK.